# How to read 3.5 inches Floppies with 1.7MB on them?

Tags: microsoft, floppy

I have an external floppy drive (Teac FD-05PUB) that reads 1.44MB Floppies fine when they are formatted normally (classic 1.44MB MS-DOS format) but fails when floppies have 1.7MB on them (Microsoft's DMF 1680K format).
How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried the 1.7 floppies in a different drive or computer? Not all drives are equal - a disc written in one drive was not always readable in another... I have assumed that the Teac is rated to read 1.7 floppies.. Not all drives were...

Comment: On what hardware and software are you using the floppy drive?

Comment: I'm trying on OS X, Not sure if the Teac can read them. I should try it on Linux.